# facebook api exception #100-invalid parameter in c#

Tags: c#, facebook, hyperlink, facebook-c#-sdk

i developing a poster software,
when i'm trying to post a link it give the following exception

facebook api exception #100-invalid

here's my code

```
     public static bool post(string accesstoken,string status,string link) {
        try
        {
            FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(accesstoken);

            Dictionary<string, object> postArgs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            postArgs["message"] = status;
            if (link != "") {
                postArgs["link"] = link;
                MessageBox.Show(link);
            }
            fb.Post("/me/feed", postArgs);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should check if the **Stream post URL security option** is on your app's dashboard, if it is turn it off: https://developers.facebook.com/apps , clic on settings and then migrations.

[image: Dashboard]

See more information in the **Migrations > Stream post URL security** bullet : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#surfacearea

Comment: This is definitely the right answer. I had a problem when I tried to share a link from facebook and when I clicked on the link, I had that 100 exception in my android app.